# My hello world flask program is not running?

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner in `Flask`, And i'm trying to create a simple `hello world` program but it's giving me errors on everytime with `Undefined variable from import: run`.

Here is my directory looks like:

```
/MyApplicationName:
      /app 
          /__init__.py
          /views.py
          /run.py
```

My `__init__.py` is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import views
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```
from app import app

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def main():
    return "Hello Flask!!"
```

Here is my last one `run.py`:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Every time it gives me this error:

`Undefined variable from import: run`.

***HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED***

Comment: Here `app` is the package name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

to views.py.  Then make `__init__.py`:

```
from views import app
```

You have a circular import, but I'm not exactly sure as to why it's throwing the error it's throwing.

Comment: It does seem strange to put the app object in views, since the point of views is to put the routes on a separate module.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, `run.py` being under `app/` was pointed out below, and it isn't right either.  I typically use `if __name__ == '__main__': app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080)` in the app.  I think you can also use `app = Flask(__name__)` or `app = flask.Flask(__name__)` in `views.py` and `import views` in your `app.py`... Not sure if it's best practices or even correct. I'll try it later and report back, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at flask-script, anyway evaluate to use a factory, something like create_app() that returns an app object.
It seems to be the common practice when using flask:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(
        'portal', static_folder='static/build', static_url_path='/static'
    )

    init_config(app)
    init_login(app)
    init_csrf(app)

    app.register_blueprint(views)

    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing a single line of what you've coded, just move run.py out of the app directory.

Your project directory should look then like this:

```
└── MyApplication
├── __init__.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── views.py
└── run.py
```

Happy coding,

J.